# Can someone explain the meaning of x, y and z coordinates in open3d pointcloud?

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, point-clouds, open3d

I am working with a depth camera. The camera outputs a depth map which is 500x500 array. Each of the elements in this array represent the depth from the camera.

Now I convert this depth map to a pointcloud using open3d library. I know that each of these point have an x,y and z coordinate. I want to know out of these three, which one represent the depth from the camera? Also, are the x and y cooridnates here are in camera frame?

Comment: Suggest mention it is an open3d pointcloud in the original question wording

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The depth map would provide the depth as the value indexed at [u,v] in the map, based on what is rendered in the depth image.

A point in the point cloud would be:

```
(u,v,depth[u+v*depth.w])
```

According to [Open3D documentation](http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.7.0/python_api/open3d.geometry.create_point_cloud_from_depth_image.html) the Z value represents the depth as a value of the equation (d/depth_scale)

Answer (score 0):

Should be z for depth

Depth as in how far from camera that pixel location is

Comment: Okay and will the x and y axis here will be in the camera frame?

Comment: yup, basically same thing as a non depth sensing camera